# rails console not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn, rbenv

I'm trying to open rails console and getting

```
deployer@microv:~$ rails console
-bash: rails: command not found
```

My environment ubuntu 12.10 postgresql rbenv-installer unicorn

Comment: After checking out if the Rails gem is installed locally , try `cd your_rails_app`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you give little information about your environment and about where and how you are using Rails, some hints:

```
$ cd path/to/rails/app
$ rails console
```

`rails console` only works in the dir where your rails app was built. You have one, don't you?

```
$ cd path/to/rails/app
$ bundle exec rails console
```

When using bundler, the binaries from the gems installed in that bundle, are only available trough the command `bundle exec`. You may have installed rails itself with bundler. Did you?

```
$ cd path/to/rails/app
$ rvm list gemsets
$ rvm use ruby-1.x.y@foo
$ rails console
```

When using rvm, rails may be installed only in one Gemset. You then have to activate that gemset in order to have access to the gems (and their bins). Are you using RVM?

Comment: Im using rbenv and I can't find Rails

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using rbenv. When installing/removing gems bundled with executables, like `rails` and many others, you have to do `rbenv rehash`.

Answer (score 0):

find a solution, just restart shell

```
$ exec $SHELL -l
```